# What does "近侍の臣" mean?

Tags: history, archaic-language, literature

I'm reading a story about ancient Japan and I have a problem with what seems to be a title of some kind (?): 近侍の臣. Here's the context:

この年の春、樹々 の芽吹く ころから、クナ国の兵がしきりに国境を侵しはじめた。ここ数年、たえて無かったことである。
辺境から報を受けたヒミコは、ただちに兵を派そうと考え、いつものように**年若い近侍の臣ヌナサキ**を通じて、群臣に諮った。すると、弟のクニヒコが、まず異を唱えた。 いま兵を動かすのは得策ではない、と言う。

Could you please help me out?

Comment: https://cjjc.weblio.jp/content/%E8%BF%91%E4%BE%8D%E4%B9%8B%E8%87%A3

Answer (score 1):

近侍 is not a common word, but it refers to someone who works near or aside a master. Perhaps "attendant", "valet" or "chamberlain" in English. 臣 is just "retainer". The の between them is an apposition marker ("近侍 who is also 臣" rather than "近侍's 臣"). 臣 may seem redundant, but it may be saying Nunasaki is not a servant but has some social status.